# Split string content by parenthesis

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
Adam Nguyen(adamnguyen)
```

What is the best way to get two strings `"Adam Nguyen"` and `"adamnguyen"`?

Answer (score 6):

```
"Adam Nguyen(adamnguyen)".split(/[()]+/)
# => ["Adam Nguyen", "adamnguyen"]
```

Comment: I tried with `.split(/[()]/)` and still get the same result. Can you please explain what does `+` sign do in this? I am not good at `REGEX`. 1+

Comment: @GaganGami Nothing wrong with your regex for this particular example. It avoids empty strings being extracted. Just to be safe in wider range of examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
name, username = /^(.*?)\s*\((.*)\)$/.match('Adam Nguyen (adamnguyen)').captures
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
name = 'Adam Nguyen(adamnguyen)'
```

If the input is always short like the example and you're not performing this operation too many times (i.e. performance is not an issue), and the format of the string is guaranteed not to vary, I find the following to be slightly more verbose, but more intelligible than regex:

```
human_readable_name, other_name = name.split('(')
other_name = other_name[0..-2]
```

But if it needs to scale, regex is the way to go:

```
human_readable_name, other_name = name.split(/[()]+/);
```

Comment: The question is about Ruby. I think you have a different language in mind.

Comment: I've been answering JavaScript questions all afternoon. That's what I get for trying to switch it up. Thanks.